# Calculate sales per day[timestamp]

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I would like to calculate the total sales per day from this table.

> date                |sales
>
> =======================
>
> 2014-10-07 03:58:45 | 649.75
>
> 2014-10-07 06:38:47 | 395
>
> 2014-10-09 18:21:27 | 149.75

I tried this one but it calculated everything in sales field.

```
select SUM(sales) from tbltransaction group by from_unixtime(date, '%Y%m%d')
```

Help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you should be using DATE_FORMAT() instead of FROM_UNIXTIME().